# Any difference between implementing and implementation

Tags: word-meaning

I use the word "Implementing" sometimes as a noun. Does it have the same meaning as "implementation"? Are they interchangeable in all contexts?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit in the sentence you want to use it in and provide more context.

Comment: Thanks, for example: Implementing the project was hard. vs Implementation of the project was hard.

Comment: *Implementing* isn't a noun in that sentence, but a verb form (a so-called "gerund-participle" – this becomes apparent when you try to put an adjective in front of it: *Careful implementing the project* ← doesn't work; *Carefully implementing the project* ← works with an adverb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing is the gerund form of implement, while implementation is a separate noun. Implementing refers to the process of implementing something, as it’s derived from the verb. Meanwhile, the implementation is the state reached once the implementing is complete.
You would say:
“Implementing this is a series of tasks”.
You could also say the “implementation of this is a series of tasks” but this would describe the implemented thing itself, rather than the process of implementing it.

I have said this word so many times it doesn’t make sense to me anymore. Cheers

Comment: I corrected some typos in your answer, in particular where *implement* was misspelled *impliment*. No doubt because of having stared at it for so long. ;)